# Create a new table using columns from other tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

Lets imagine I have bunch of referential tables, and I'd like to have one table consist of

```
Fcttbl[ID]
Ref_Product[Product]
Ref_Country[Country]
Ref_Category[Category]
Ref_Subcategory[Color]
```

All of these are connected to `Fcttbl`, but no other connections between them, if that count

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Summarize(). If this will not help then add a dummy tables and result sample.

```
SUMMARIZE(
    Fcttbl
    ,Fcttbl[ID]
    ,Ref_Product[Product]
    ,Ref_Country[Country]
    ,Ref_Category[Category]
    ,Ref_Subcategory[Color]
)
```